# Upgrading to Rails 5 and rspec 3.7 no longer sends emails via ActionMailer::Base.deliveries

Tags: email, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, actionmailer

I had a functional spec suite using rspec with a Rails 4.2.8.  I upgraded to Rails 5.0.6 and rspec 3.7 accordingly.

Many of the specs work, but none of my specs that send emails actually add the email to the `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries` array.

I've verified that `config/environments/test/rb` has `config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test`, which *should* add any sent emails to the array instead of actually sending them.

I suspect it has something to do with `ActiveJob` as well, because when I send an email via `SomeMailer.some_method().deliver_later` in my specs, it returns an `ActionMailer::DeliveryJob` object, but it does not add anything to the `ActionMailer::Base` array.

When I call `SomeMailer.some_method().deliver_now`, I find the emails actually are added to the `ActionMailer::Base` array.  I'm wondering if for my specs I just need to configure them to all use `deliver_now` instead of `deliver_later`?

I've reviewed and followed the Ruby on Rails upgrade guide from 4.2 -> 5.0 and can't figure this out.

My specs with emails follow the format:

```
# spec/models/record_spec.rb
require "rails_helper"

describe Model do
  describe "#method" do
    it "sends email" do
      record = Record.create(attributes = {})
      RecordMailer.welcome_email(record).deliver_later

      last_email = ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last
      expect(last_email.subject).eq ("Welcome")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Yeah delayed jobs don't get run unless you deliberately run them. You could change everything to "now" or you could just manually run the delayed jobs... In our app we use Sidekiq (instead of `ActiveJob`) and then just do `Sidekiq::Worker.drain_all` before checking if the email has been delivered... YMMV :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're including **ActiveJob::TestHelper** somewhere, you can wrap your **deliver_later** (or if in a feature spec, for example, a button click triggering the delivery) inside a **perform_enqueued_jobs** block:

```
perform_enqueued_jobs do
    RecordMailer.welcome_email(record).deliver_later
end
```

Now your **ActionMailer::Base.deliveries** should contain the email sent via ActiveJob.